# Windows 7 Boot to VHD for SP2010

Tags: development

I am looking for a definitive "how to" guide on setting up Windows 7 x64 boot to VHD for my SP2010 VMs ... anyone care to share blog/whitepaper?

Comment: I would add to this question: is there a native-boot-enabled vhd available somewhere for dev/test purposes?

Comment: There isn't a native bootable vhd available unfortunately. However you can download the Microsoft Information Worker SharePoint 2010 vhd and make it bootable - have a look at this post on my blog which explains how to do it - http://sharepointcoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/boot-to-vhd-with-the-sharepoint-information-worker-vhd-for-those-with-4gb-of-ram-or-less/

Comment: It's worth to know that if you are converting the IW 2010 VHD you might have to rearm it directly when it has booted up for the first time - you have changed all the HW for the image...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from alex350r:

http://sharepointcoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/

> There isn't a native bootable vhd available unfortunately. However you can download the Microsoft Information Worker SharePoint 2010 vhd and make it bootable - have a look at this post on my blog which explains how to do it - sharepointcoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/06/…

Answer (score 3):

Scott Hanselman has a pretty good blog post about booting from a VHD
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[This MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx) should help, refer to end of the Article.

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote one similar; it's for booting from a USB stick, but there are some resources for getting your bootable VHD off the ground. It's pretty quick and dirty.

http://www.johndandison.com/blog/post/2010/02/25/Boot-to-Windows-7-VHD-with-a-Portable-USB-BCD-Bootloader.aspx